# Auto restore doesn't work

Tags: applications, backup, moto-x, google-backup

I just switched from a Nexus 4 to Moto X 2nd generation this morning. I had backup ON on my nexus 4. When I added my account on the new phone I expected all the apps and related data to get restored on it. But this didn't happen, I removed and re added my account, even ran a factory reset but nothing helped. How do I get all my apps and data back(without having to manually reinstall all of it).